# Changing the default date and time format in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I was looking for a way to change the default date format in Rails 4.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Found a nice approach through the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#how-to-store-your-custom-translations)

Data and time formats can be 'translated' by adding the format to the i18n configuration.

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y"
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
```

Note: remember to not have tabs for the indent, like I did first time :)

---

As mentioned by NoelProf in the comments

> To use i18n conversion don't forget the l (lower case L) before your
>   date in views! For example: <%= l your_date %>

You are invited to comment if you found other ways working well.

Comment: awesome.. saved me some time :)

Comment: To use i18n conversion don't forget the l (lower case L) before your date in views! For example: `<%= l your_date %>`

Answer (score 36):

Add this

```
# Date
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y" 

# Time
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
```

to config/initializers/date_time.rb

Then **restart the server**.

Comment: Is it typical to use `date_time.rb` as the file name? I know it doesn't matter but in the code example from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s it shows `time_format.rb`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use i18n conversion don't forget the `l` method before your dates in views!

```
<%= l your_date %>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please edit your answer to make it for the questioner better to understand your solution.