# How to add datetimepicker to a textbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker

I am having a text_field_tag in rails.

```
<%=text_field_tag 'promocode_expiration','',class: "promoExp form-control",id: "datetimepicker1",size: 10%>
```

On click of this text_field i wish to open a datetimepicker, to add date to the field.

How can i achieve it? Can anyone help please? thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless you use a gem, I don't think it's possible in Rails. Maybe some Javascript/Jquery plugin?

Comment: You can refer the below link... [Refer Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096517/jquery-datepicker-with-rails-4)

Comment: @Bharatsoni I refered the link and i also tried the options from it, but its not working.

Comment: @vishal if you are programmer then it's the simplest things to add a datepicker on the input field. I am wondering you have created a question for the same.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined This is the error i am getting in my console.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this two line :

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.37'
```

Then, You need to do :

```
$ bundle
```

Then, Add the following to your JavaScript manifest file (application.js):

```
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

And, modify your application.css and add :

```
*= require bootstrap
*= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

And Lastly, In your view file :

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

This had worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jquery datetimepicker gem to add this functionality. Here is the link: https://github.com/Envek/jquery-datetimepicker-rails

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But I tried it out. but not worked.

Comment: What you did? http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ this is the documentation, please go through it.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add datapicker Gem into your Gemfile

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

run `bundle install`

Add this line to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

Add this line to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

in view just paste html code

```
<input type="text" data-provide='datepicker' >
```

or

```
<input type="text" class='datepicker' >

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to provide an alternatice gem, which doesn't have any other dependency;

```
gem 'laydate-rails'
```

https://github.com/AlbaHoo/laydate-rails, 
it's working well.