# DateTimePicker not updating values on ruby side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am having an issue where the regular datepicker updates the value on the rails side in this format `'2017-09-12 22:49:27'`, but I am trying to use datetimepicker and its not updating the value, it updates the text field with the format: `M/DD/YYYY` but not the actual value in the param as I need that in `'2017-09-12 22:49:27'` format but its staying the same value which is currently `MM/DD/YYYY` as what's loaded up for the text field and I am getting an `undefined` value when I try to see the current value:

```
var selectedDate = $("#from").find(".active").data("day");
```

Here is the ruby code

```
= text_field_tag :from_js, l((params[:from].to_datetime or @item.created_at), format: :american_no_time), class: 'form-control input-sm datetimepicker', id:  'from'
= hidden_field_tag :from, l((params[:from].to_datetime or @item.created_at), format: :american_no_time)

= text_field_tag :to_js, l((params[:to].to_datetime or Time.zone.now.to_datetime), format: :american_no_time), class: 'form-control input-sm datetimepicker', id: 'to'
= hidden_field_tag :to, l((params[:to].to_datetime or Time.zone.now.to_datetime), format: :american_no_time)
```

and here is the current javascript:

```
var maxDate = new Date();
var minDate = $("#from").val();
$(function () {
  $('#from').datetimepicker({
    format: "M/D/YYYY",
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    pickTime: false
  });

  $('#to').datetimepicker({
    format: "M/D/YYYY",
    minDate: minDate,
    maxDate: maxDate,
    pickTime: false
  });
});
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Did you tried option `format` in datetimepicker ? also you can get specific format by using method `strftime`

Comment: yea the datetimepicker has a format I updated it with the above sorry forgot to add. But it still doesnt update the input value to the param because I need to use that data to render a sql query

Comment: can you also please add link of plugin that you have used ?

Comment: Here it is: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: potentially duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096517/jquery-datepicker-with-rails-4?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Not the same as mine works fine with datepicker updating the value but not datetimepicker.

Comment: still need help with this problem..