# Changing datetime formatting while deserilizing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, serialization, delayed-job

I'm using `rails 4`. I need to have a global datetime format to be set as `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"` i.e. `2015-07-29 02:34:38 +0530`.
I tried to override as_json method which works but when I'm using it with `delayed_job`, It's serializing object which converts datetime field into `2015-07-29 02:34:38 UTC`.

```
class ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
  def as_json(options = {})
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
  end
end
```

Will it work if `serializable_hash` method overriden globally? If yes, how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by overriding `TimeZoneCOnverter`.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module AttributeMethods
    module TimeZoneConversion
      class TimeZoneConverter
        def convert_time_to_time_zone(value)
          if value.is_a?(Array)
            value.map { |v| convert_time_to_time_zone(v) }
          elsif value.acts_like?(:time)
            # changed from value.in_time_zone to
            value.to_time
          else
            value
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`delayed_job` serializes the object's attributes by saving it's `type` and `value` 
for time zone object type is `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::TimeZoneConversion::TimeZoneConverter` whose `deserialize` method calls `convert_time_to_time_zone(value)`, by overriding it I got format that I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `to_json` only changes the behavior when the TimeWithZone instance is serialized into JSON; however, as you've perhaps noticed, DelayedJob serializes into YAML. You can just tell Rails to use a default date/time format everywhere, though, with the methods from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870762/changing-the-default-date-and-time-format-in-rails-4). For example, add a file named `config/initializers/datetime.rb` with the contents:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"
```

Which will override the default format for every time a Time is converted to a string.

Comment: I had tried that as well, but still returning in `2015-07-21 16:01:33 UTC` this format only

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from an inconsistent overriding of as_json that only applies to instances of TimeWithZone but does not effect the as_json monkey patching of Time, Date, and DateTime.

My tmp fix:

```
# config/initializers/time_with_zone.rb

module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    def as_json(options = nil)
      iso8601
    end
  end
end
```