# DRY views strftime call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view of my model with many date fields rendered.

What I want to do is call `strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')` on each date field I have.

```
- @items.each do |item| 
  = item.date_field.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M') 
  = item.date_field1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

Any ideas on how I can to DRY this? I tried to make `to_s` method in my model, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Update:

I defined this method:

```
def to_s(date)
  send(date).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
end
```

So I can:

```
- @items.each do |item| 
  = item.to_s(:date_field)
  = item.to_s(:date_field1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the default date and time format in Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870762/changing-the-default-date-and-time-format-in-rails-4)

Comment: Can you post the view or an example of it?

Comment: @CdotStrifeVII
Example:
`- @items.each do |item|`

  `= item.date_field.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')`
  `= item.date_field1.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')`
  `= ...`

Comment: Not supporting the close vote on this, the question, as phrased, is not about **changing the default time format** but **drying up code in views**.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Please add code to the question, not to comments--it's impossible to understand your intent.

Comment: I just came up with this bunch of code in my model
`def to_s(date)`
  `send(date).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')`
`end`

Comment: I may have been misunderstood. **Please add code to the question, not to comments.** I don't understand why you're using `send` there, you can call `strftime` directly on the `date` parameter. If nothing else, you're using `send` wrong.

Comment: I will really prefer either `helper` or `localization` with customized format

Comment: @SumLare What happens if you call `item.id.to_s` or any other field?

Comment: @Deepak I got it now, I'll use option 2 for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a helper (in application_helper.rb if you are using it application wide)

**Option 1**

```
def customized_time_format(time)
  time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
end
```

and make use of it in your views

```
- @items.each do |item| 
  = customized_time_format(item.date_field)
  = customized_time_format(item.date_field1)
```

**Option2**

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    formats:
      customized: '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'
```

And use it

```
- @items.each do |item| 
  = l(item.date_field, format: :customized)
  = l(item.date_field1, format: :customized)
```

Comment: That is good approach, but I need this method only for one model. I guess `customized_time_format` method is better to be defined in my model.

Comment: @SumLare I would use option 2 personally, but if you use 1 I wouldn't put it in your model, if you need it on another model later you have to move it.

Comment: Option 2 is much better IMO