# Rails 5 - default datetime format to RFC3339

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an API, and I'd like to format every datetime in RFC3339 automatically rather than having to specify each manually. Is there an elegant way to do that, or do I just have to override the DateTime#to_s method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the default date and time format in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870762/changing-the-default-date-and-time-format-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a file under `initializers/time_formats.rb`

```
# config/initializers/time_formats.rb
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%Y-%m-%d"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetime formats can be 'formated' by adding the format to the i18n configuration.

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%D/%MM/%YYY"
  time:
    formats:
      default: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
```